# Custom font iOS 8 not effect in device

Tags: ios8, xcode6

i am using Xcode 6.4 beta and i have issue with custom font

> custom font ios 8 storyboard working but in device not working

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Include your fonts in your XCode project

Step 2: Make sure that the target you want to use your font in is checked under “Target Membership, double check that your fonts are included as Resources in your bundle

Step 3: Include your iOS custom fonts in your application plist

Step 4: Find the name of the font, the tricky part is that the font name may not be what you expect

```
for (NSString* family in [UIFont familyNames])
{
    NSLog(@"%@", family);

    for (NSString* name in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName: family])
    {
        NSLog(@"  %@", name);
    }
}
```

use above code to find the name

Step 5: Use UIFont and specify the name of the font

And finally, you can simply display your custom font using UIFont and whatever UILabel or text view you want.

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 60)];
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
label.text = @"Using Custom Fonts";
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Neutraface2Display-Titling" size:20];
```

Comment: i found font name in font family but still not effect

Comment: are you getting your family like step 4 code and have followed my steps? You have to add some breakpoints and debug it will your device to see if the font is really installed. You may provide some useful logs and your code so we can no better. Otherwise we cannot help. The steps I gave you is proven working

Comment: i use same code in different project its working fine but only work in my working project

Comment: If it's working in another project, but not in your current project, it's a simple error.  Double-check all the steps.  Make sure you've added it to the correct target's Info.plist, as the Test target plist also has the same name.